# SQL error message - Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server

I get this error message

> "Incorrect syntax near ')'."

from the `sum(PayHours)` line and I would appreciate a bit of guidance on how to go about solving it. I am stuck.

`[#PremierThree]` from code below is a temporary table being created on the fly and drop afterwards

```
SELECT * 
FROM [#PremierThree]
PIVOT 
    (SUM(PayHours)
     FOR [Pay_ClassHrs] IN ([PBS_Hrs], [POT_Hrs], [PED_Hrs], [POR_Hrs],   [Agency_Hrs], [PWH_Hrs], [Sick_Hrs], [PTO_Hrs], [Holiday_Hrs], [PJB_Hrs], [Bugeted_Work_Hrs], [Bugeted_Benefit_Hrs])
    ) AS pvt1
PIVOT 
    (SUM(PayAmount)
     FOR [Pay_Class$] in ([PBS_$], [POT_$], [PED_$], [POR_$], [Agency_$], [PWH_$], [Sick_$], [PTO_$], [Holiday_$], [PJB_$], [PNH_$],[Bugeted_Work_$], [Bugeted_Benefit_$])
    ) AS pvt2
ORDER BY
    [Facility], CAST([Job_Code] AS INT)
```

Comment: Your parents are pretty obviously unbalanced. ) ) as pvt1... why two close parens for only one open paren?

Comment: compiles successfully for me

Comment: You don't need all those square brackets, they are just making this a LOT harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot query does not contain 2 or more pivot clauses in T-SQL see [FROM - Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)

You are attempting to output Hours and Dollars as "2 column sets" and frankly I find the T-SQL implementation of pivot too limiting for that. You could try an approach of using unpivot and pivot together to get the effect you want ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274305/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-pivots-using-the-same-pivot-column-using-sql-ser)).

Personally I would go for a more traditional style of pivot query that simply uses `GROUP BY` and `case expressions` as necessary (the style we always had to use before "pivot was added to SQL at all).  e.g. (but I leave the column aliases up to you)

```
SELECT
      [Facility]
    , [Job_Code]

    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'PBS_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)             AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'POT_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)             AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'PED_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)             AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'POR_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)             AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'Agency_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)          AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'PWH_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)             AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'Sick_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)            AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'PTO_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)             AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'Holiday_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)         AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'PJB_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)             AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'Bugeted_Work_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END)    AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_ClassHrs = 'Bugeted_Benefit_Hrs' THEN Pay_ClassHrs END) AS x

    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'POT_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)                   AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'PED_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)                   AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'POR_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)                   AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'Agency_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)                AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'PWH_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)                   AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'Sick_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)                  AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'PTO_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)                   AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'Holiday_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)               AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'PJB_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)                   AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'PNH_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)                   AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'Bugeted_Work_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)          AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Pay_Class$ = 'Bugeted_Benefit_$' THEN Pay_Class$ END)       AS x

FROM [#PremierThree]
GROUP BY
      [Facility]
    , [Job_Code]
```

---

**UNTESTED!**

If the above approach looks too old hat and wordy for you. Try combining the 2 pivots using a join, below I have assumed it would need a `full outer join` but it might work with a simpler `inner join` if both subqueries produce the same rows (*which is quite likely in your case using that temp table*).

```
SELECT
       COALESCE(p1.Facility,p2.Facility) Facility
     , COALESCE(p1.Job_Code,p2.Job_Code) Job_Code
     , [PBS_Hrs], [POT_Hrs], [PED_Hrs], [POR_Hrs],   [Agency_Hrs], [PWH_Hrs], [Sick_Hrs], [PTO_Hrs], [Holiday_Hrs], [PJB_Hrs], [Bugeted_Work_Hrs], [Bugeted_Benefit_Hrs]
     , [PBS_$], [POT_$], [PED_$], [POR_$], [Agency_$], [PWH_$], [Sick_$], [PTO_$], [Holiday_$], [PJB_$], [PNH_$],[Bugeted_Work_$], [Bugeted_Benefit_$]
FROM (
      SELECT
            [Facility]
          , [Job_Code]
          , [PBS_Hrs], [POT_Hrs], [PED_Hrs], [POR_Hrs],   [Agency_Hrs], [PWH_Hrs], [Sick_Hrs], [PTO_Hrs], [Holiday_Hrs], [PJB_Hrs], [Bugeted_Work_Hrs], [Bugeted_Benefit_Hrs]
      FROM [#PremierThree]
      PIVOT 
          (SUM(PayHours)
           FOR [Pay_ClassHrs] IN ([PBS_Hrs], [POT_Hrs], [PED_Hrs], [POR_Hrs],   [Agency_Hrs], [PWH_Hrs], [Sick_Hrs], [PTO_Hrs], [Holiday_Hrs], [PJB_Hrs], [Bugeted_Work_Hrs], [Bugeted_Benefit_Hrs])
          ) AS pvt1
      ) AS p1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
            [Facility]
          , [Job_Code]
          , [PBS_$], [POT_$], [PED_$], [POR_$], [Agency_$], [PWH_$], [Sick_$], [PTO_$], [Holiday_$], [PJB_$], [PNH_$],[Bugeted_Work_$], [Bugeted_Benefit_$]
      PIVOT 
          (SUM(PayAmount)
           FOR [Pay_Class$] in ([PBS_$], [POT_$], [PED_$], [POR_$], [Agency_$], [PWH_$], [Sick_$], [PTO_$], [Holiday_$], [PJB_$], [PNH_$],[Bugeted_Work_$], [Bugeted_Benefit_$])
          ) AS pvt2
      ) AS p2
             ON p1.Facility = p2.Facility AND p1.Job_Code = p2.Job_Code
ORDER BY
    [Facility], CAST([Job_Code] AS INT)
;
```

For T-SQL: Personally, even with a join approach I don't see any advantage to using pivot when it starts to get complex.