# SQL Server : how to pivot where new columns have multiple unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Using this table :

```
| CUST | PRODUCT | QTY | SMALLEST |
-----------------------------------
|    E |    1600 |   2 |        1 |
|    F |    1600 |   6 |        9 |
|    G |    1600 |   1 |        8 |
```

I want to pivot it to make it look like this:

```
|    E    |    F    |   G    |
------------------------------
|    1600 |    1600 |   1600 |
|    2    |    6    |   1    |
|    1    |    9    |   8    |
```

I get how to do this with one unique row. If I only have QTY or only have SMALLEST it works fine with this query for example:

Query

```
SELECT E, F, G
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (E,F,G)) AS pvt
```

Output

```
| E | F | G |
-------------
| 2 | 6 | 1 |
```

But, if I add another column to the concoction in another query, I get this mess:

Query

```
SELECT E, F, G
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY, SMALLEST
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (E,F,G)) AS pvt
```

Output

```
|      E |      F |      G |
----------------------------
|      2 | (null) | (null) |
| (null) | (null) |      1 |
| (null) |      6 | (null) |
```

And it's easy to see why when I change the query:

Query

```
SELECT product,smallest, E, F, G
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY, SMALLEST
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (E,F,G)) AS pvt
```

Output

```
| PRODUCT | SMALLEST |      E |      F |      G |
-------------------------------------------------
|    1600 |        1 |      2 | (null) | (null) |
|    1600 |        8 | (null) | (null) |      1 |
|    1600 |        9 | (null) |      6 | (null) |
```

The pattern becomes obvious. It's finding where there is 1600 and 1 there is one E value: 2, where there is 1600 and 8 there is one F value 6, etc.

I get the problem, but I have no clue how to fix it. Can someone aid me in my futile quest?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d929a/5)

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really you want an `UNPIVOT` to take care of the multiple columns, then a `PIVOT` to get your data.  My favorite way of doing an [`UNPIVOT` is to use `CROSS APPLY`](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/04/01/unpivot-a-table-using-cross-apply/), but you can do it however you want.  Like such.

```
SELECT E, F, G
FROM (
SELECT CUST, ColumnName, Value
FROM Product
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ('PRODUCT', PRODUCT),
                        ('QTY', QTY),
                        ('SMALLEST',SMALLEST)) 
    UnPivoted(ColumnName, Value)) up
PIVOT (SUM(VALUE) FOR CUST IN (E,F,G)) AS pvt
```

And of course if you want to see what column the values are coming from:

```
SELECT ColumnName, E, F, G
FROM (
SELECT CUST, ColumnName, Value
FROM Product
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ('PRODUCT', PRODUCT),
                        ('QTY', QTY),
                        ('SMALLEST',SMALLEST)) 
    UnPivoted(ColumnName, Value)) up
PIVOT (SUM(VALUE) FOR CUST IN (E,F,G)) AS pvt
```

EDIT:

Here is a solution for multiple types.  Basically you have to have do multiple queries, one for each data type.  Among other things you have a `SUM` in your numeric query that won't work on varchar columns.  Your output also has to be all the same.  Meaning you have to convert any numeric or date columns into varchar.

```
SELECT ColumnName, CAST(E AS varchar(30)) E, CAST(F AS varchar(30)) F, CAST(G AS varchar(30)) G
FROM (
SELECT CUST, ColumnName, Value
FROM Product
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ('PRODUCT', PRODUCT),
                        ('QTY', QTY),
                        ('SMALLEST',SMALLEST)) 
    UnPivoted(ColumnName, Value)) up
PIVOT (SUM(VALUE) FOR CUST IN (E,F,G)) AS pvt
UNION ALL
SELECT ColumnName, E, F, G
FROM (
SELECT CUST, ColumnName, Value
FROM Product
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ('CharColA', CharColA),
                        ('CharColB', CharColB)) 
    UnPivoted(ColumnName, Value)) up
PIVOT (MIN(VALUE) FOR CUST IN (E,F,G)) AS pvt
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work with varchar columns? After adding one, I get the error "Error converting data type varchar to float."

Comment: The columns in the CROSS APPLY have to all end up as the same type for it to work this way since they are all ending up in the same column at one point.  You could convert everything to varchar though.  Or do it in 2 different groups of queries. One for numeric values and another for varchar.  Then `UNION ALL` the queries together.

Comment: At what point in the query do i convert to varchar? That would be a good option for me, but I can't just cast(values as char) can I?

Comment: I mean, is there a way to do the conversion in one line and keep it as pretty as it looks now? I know I can convert each column if I have to

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way! Very concise answer!

Comment: No problems.  I've expanded my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `CROSS-APPLY` and `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT E,F,G
FROM
(
  SELECT Cust,col,value
  FROM #Product
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    VALUES ('E', Product),('F', QTY),('G', SMALLEST)
  ) C (COL, VALUE)
) SRC
PIVOT
(
  MAX(VALUE)
  FOR CUST IN (E,F,G)
) PIV
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d929a/33/0)

Comment: I like it for the most part, but it seems like your query will just get huge for larger numbers of columns. Thanks for the speedy reply! +1

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking on a better way, guessing someone else will have one.

Comment: I think what I need to do is unpivot and then pivot like this threads talks about, but I'm not sure - [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694691/sql-server-pivot-table-with-multiple-column-aggregates)

Comment: I was just reading an answer like that:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table

Comment: Updated to use `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: Ah, Kenneth beat me to it, I just used Bluefeet's answer from the thread above and popped in your code.

Comment: You were really helpful, though. Thanks!